# XGBoost heavily overfitting when containing the minimum/maximum of a variable?

Tags: boosting, hyperparameter

I've been building an XGBoost Regressor model with some good success. Currently, the training accuracy is 68% and testing 66% - indicating some, but not too much, overfitting.

However, I've noticed today a strange behaviour:

Let's say the model had 2 independent features, I'll call them X and Z, and then it's trying to predict the likelihood of event Y (either 1 or 0). We'll say X and Z are normally distributed between 0 and 1. Let's also assume that X is highly +correlated to Y, and Z is less so but still +correlated. We have also added monotonic constraints to X and Z, so that if all else is equal then increasing them will only increase the model prediction of Y.

What I'm seeing is that in a "normal" prediction if X is say, 0.1 and Z is 0.1 then the model predicted probability of Y is 10%

If you increase Z to 0.5, then the model predicted probability of Y goes to 15%..

If you increase Z to 0.95, then the model predicted probability of Y goes to 20%..

But when Z is 1 then the model predicted probability of Y is suddenly 90% likely! The reason, I think, is because in the training dataset the maximum value of Z is 1, and when Z was this value, Y was 1. So it's like the model has hyper overfit to this one row of data? It's very strange, as like I say the model in general doesn't seem overfit - but it has this very weird interaction with the row that contains the maximum value?

Is there a specific type of parameter or technique that can help defend against this type of interaction?

Reshuffling the train/test dataset isn't possible as it's timebased and so they are split by a date (before date = train, after date = test).

A Partial Dependency Plot (from the actual model), where X=feature[0] and Z=feature[20]. It shows what I expect to see from the model - however the prediction still jumps (from 16% to 73%!) after Z (feature[20]) goes higher than the training set maximum of 2.16.

[image: Partial Dependency Plot (from actual model, )]

Comment: Could you show us partial dependence plots for the two variables? I think it would help to see where the prediction function jumps.

Comment: @MichaelM, just added one - weird thing is it looks as expected..
However, when feature X = 0.27 and Z = 2.16 the prediction is 16% and 
when I put it Z = 2.17 it suddenly shoots up to 73%. It's only at this exact point that it switches. Every other number below 2.17 sees normal behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. Thx! Do you see similar behavior without mononucleosis constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right in diagnosing what went wrong, and yes there are techniques to mitigate this. Xgboost offers regularization options to make sure nodes have "enough" data. The "gamma" parameter does this by requiring a minimum improvement in the training objective - you should be able to increase gamma to a point where this value isn't being singled out.

There is also a "min_child_weight" parameter - if you are using the sum of squared errors objective this is just a minimum number of rows per node. Increasing this should also be able to prevent the problem.

But even more simply, if you **know** that you only have one row with this value, and you know you never want your decision trees to use this feature to distinguish that record, you could always just cap the variable at some lower threshold before training the model.

Comment: Thanks, I've experimented with the two parameters above and although they do reduce model overfitting - this strange behaviour persists! 

The problem with simply capping the datapoint is that I have 30+ features and I believe it may be a problem with them all so manual intervention doesn't seem wise. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a principal component analysis as a data preparation step and use the principal components as predictors instead of the original variables.  The highly correlated variables should get collapsed into a smaller number of principal components.  What would this accomplish?  Hard for me to answer.  Perhaps make it more robust to noise in the predictors?  Make the partial dependency plots more valid?

A few things to keep in mind

- Partial dependency plots are kind of problematic in that they purport to show the isolated effect of one variable, but due to multicollinearity in the training data the way the tree regression works, [this is not exactly what you are seeing](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pdp.html#:%7E:text=The%20partial%20dependence%20plot%20%28short%20PDP%20or%20PD,a%20feature%20is%20linear%2C%20monotonic%20or%20more%20complex.)
- Tree regression models are unable to extrapolate, so if you have two variables highly correlated in your training data, and you predict on a new data set with a different relationship between the variables, it may give poor predictions